# Grouping labels and concatenating their text values (like a pivot table)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I've got a spreadsheet with data like this:

```
Product   | Attribute
----------+----------
Product A | Cyan
Product B | Cyan
Product C | Cyan
Product A | Magenta
Product C | Magenta
Product B | Yellow
Product C | Yellow
Product A | Black
Product B | Black
```

What I'd like to do group everything by Column A and have Column B be a comma-delimited list of values that share Column A in common, like so:

```
Product   | Attribute
----------+--------------------------
Product A | Cyan,Magenta,Black
Product B | Cyan,Yellow,Black
Product C | Cyan,Magenta,Yellow,Black
```

Unfortunately, Pivot Tables only know how to work with number values, and the furthest it goes towards this is counting the number of times Column A occurs.

I was able to pull this off ultimately by importing the data into a MySQL database and using MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT(Attribute)` function in a query with a `GROUP BY Product` clause, but after banging my head on my desk repeatedly while attempting to figure out an Excel solution.

For future reference, is this possible in Excel without macros? Whether it is or not, how would one pull this off?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
   |     A     |     B
---+-----------+-----------
 1 |  PRODUCT  | ATTRIBUTE
 2 | Product A | Cyan
 3 | Product B | Cyan
 4 | Product C | Cyan
 5 | Product A | Magenta
 6 | Product C | Magenta
 7 | Product B | Yellow
 8 | Product C | Yellow
 9 | Product A | Black
10 | Product B | Black
```

Assuming row 1:1 is header row.

1. **Sort** by column A to group by product
2. **Prepare data in comma-separated format in column C** by entering into C2 the following formula and copy down to C3:C10.

   ```
   =IF(A2<>A1, B2, C1 & "," & B2)
   ```
3. **Identify useful rows** by entering into D2 `=A2<>A3` and copy down to D3:D10.
4. Copy column C:D, then **paste special** as value (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>). You will now get:

   ```
   Product A    Cyan       Cyan                   FALSE
   Product A    Magenta    Cyan,Magenta           FALSE
   Product A    Black      Cyan,Magenta,Black     TRUE
   Product B    Cyan       Cyan                   FALSE
   Product B    Yellow     Cyan,Yellow            FALSE
   Product B    Black      Cyan,Yellow,Black      TRUE
   Product C    Cyan       Cyan                   FALSE
   Product C    Magenta    Cyan,Magenta           FALSE
   Product C    Yellow     Cyan,Magenta,Yellow    TRUE
   ```
5. **Remove useless rows** by filtering `FALSE` in column D with AutoFilter, then delete those rows.
6. **Finish**. Column A & C is what you need.

Comment: That is using your imagination! Congrats!

Comment: While this works, times have changed since 2012.  Look below for a new answer that uses the PowerQuery add-in (which is built-in to Excel 2016).  It couldn't be easier. Well, maybe talking to the computer and asking it to "group my data!"  Maybe in another 6 years.

Answer (score 19):

I know it is an old post but I had this challenge today.  I used the [PowerQuery](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379&CorrelationId=7dcca146-7cc8-48fe-8bcd-a705a63fa52b) add-in from Microsoft (NOTE: it is built into Excel 2016 by default).

1. Select your table
2. Under the POWER QUERY tab (or DATA in 2016), select "From Table"
3. Click on the "Product" column
4. under the Transform tab, select "Group By"
5. On the View tab, make sure "Formula Bar" is checked
6. Change the formula

   FROM:

   ```
   = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Product"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}})
   ```

   TO:

   ```
   = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Product"}, {{"Attributes", each Text.Combine([Attribute], ", "), type text}})
   ```

   [image: Click here for picture depicting steps from above]

Step 6 is leveraging the Power Query (M) Formulas to perform data manipulations not exposed through the basic operations provided in the UI.  Microsoft has a full reference available online for all the advanced functions available in Power Query.

Comment: Very elegant solution, probably the best of all.

Comment: @matt poland, I wonder if you know how to also remove duplicate values along the lines using this pretty awesome trick?

Comment: At STEP 1 (after selecting the table) you should be able to go to the Data tab in the ribbon and click "Remove Duplicates".

Comment: There's another option within Power Query if you don't want to alter your original table.  After STEP 2, you can hold CTRL and click both columns so that they're both selected.  Then you right click one of the columns and select "Remove Duplicates".  Then proceed to STEP 3.

Comment: Thank you!  This is the best answer.   For those using Excel 2016, PowerQuery is built in.  Simply press the Data tab and then press "From Table/Range" in the "Get & Transform Data" section.    Power Query Editor will open, press the View tab and enable the Formula Bar.  The rest of the instructions work as is.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of approaches, both "non-macro"...

1. With a small data set, after first sorting it by product (similar to GROUP BY Product), you could first copy the "Product" column, paste it elsewhere, then remove duplicates.  Next, copy the "Attributes" for each product and "paste special, TRANSPOSE" next to each Product.  Then concatenate a comma with each of your transposed attributes in a final results column.  Admittedly all this "copy/paste special/transpose" would get old quickly if you have a long list of Products.
2. If you have lots of data, using a few formulas you can work your way to the final result, as shown below.  The formulas in F2, G2, H2, I2 and N2 are indicated by the blue arrows.  Copy those to the rows below as needed.  Note that J2:L2 use the same formula as I2.  Also, the F2 formula refers to a named range "Products" that spans the range A:A .

[image]

Comment: These are good solutions, though only if the data set is small, like you say. Thanks!