# Removing duplicate values in a cell

Tags: worksheet-function

I found a great post answering ALMOST what I need.
I want to list values as such; (so that the true line is the only one I want)

Product A    Cyan       Cyan                   FALSE
Product A    Magenta    Cyan,Magenta           FALSE
Product A    Black      Cyan,Magenta,Black     TRUE

(Original question here ~ [Grouping labels and concatenating their text values (like a pivot table)](https://superuser.com/questions/453041/grouping-labels-and-concatenating-their-text-values-like-a-pivot-table#new-answer?newreg=ffb10bd689584703a9e3e7013d38df85))

However sometimes my last cell appears with duplicate values, like
Cyan, Magenta, Black, Cyan, Cyan

How would I eliminate the value adding to the string, or remove it as a duplicate?